# Sessions in Codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter

I am using sessions to store data from my multi step form so that when the user completes all three sections of the form then the information is inserted in to the database. I have built the form so that the user can go back to any stage and modify the information they have submitted, the thing is though, the values that repopulate the form are stored in sessions so if the user leaves the form page and goes elsewhere in the website and then returns to the form the information is still in the form…is there a better way to do this? I want the data destroyed if they leave the form…

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form exists only in one controller and isn't spread across multiple ones, you could simply unset all session values in the `__construct` of every other controller. (You could extend the base controller if you have lots to save the hassle of adding this functionality to many.

That way if the user visits another section, the values will be lost, but providing they remain within the "form" they can remain intact.

Comment: Ah nice solution - yes my form is one controller, so I can do this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could with JavaScript and the unload event, but it'll prove tricky since unload may fire with each "section" of the form.

Comment: also javascript isn't 100% reliable as it can be disabled, might be an issue if the data is sensitive etc

Comment: I totally agree, but it is common practice.